# xcode4 and nodejs: how to import?

Tags: c++, node.js, xcode4

I'm working on a project to test and debug them nodejs-foo. I would like to use Xcode4 as the IDE. I tried to import nodejs-project-code from github into xcode. But because I'm new to Xcode at all I don't know where to start and what to do.

I found [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Porting/Conceptual/PortingUnix/preparing/preparing.html) on *developer.apple.com* but I'm not sure how helpful it really is.

How can I import an existing None-Xcode-project into Xcode?

Comment: If you solved the question, feel free to write an answer to this and accept it, so that others might benefit from your solution in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by myself by browsing around the Google v8 docs. After calling ./configure you only have to call ./tools/gyp_node inside the source folder to build a project-file for xcode!